# Reauthentication behavior of SCP with curly braces

Tags: bash, scp

I have the following files on a server:

```
A_Hello.txt
B_Hello.txt
C_Hello.txt
A_World.txt
B_World.txt
C_World.txt
A_SU.txt
B_SU.txt
C_SU.txt
A_IDONTWANTTHISFILE.txt
```

If I try to download the desired files (all except the last one):

```
scp me@server:/path/to/*_{Hello,World,SU}.txt
```

I get asked for my password each transition of the word in the curly braces, so:

1. I execute the command and enter my server password
2. The first 3 files get downloaded
3. I get asked for my password
4. The next 3 files get downloaded
5. I get asked for my password .... etc

*What is the cause and how can I get rid of it?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the cause

The bash expansion is the answer. Your command

```
scp me@server:/path/to/*_{Hello,World,SU}.txt
```

expands to

```
scp me@server:/path/to/*_Hello.txt me@server:/path/to/*_World.txt me@server:/path/to/*_SU.txt
```

in your `bash`, which means that you issue three separate connection to the same server.

> how can I get rid of it?

This depends. There are more possibilities.

- Set up ControlMaster so you will issue all the commands over the same connection:

  create `~/.ssh/config`

  ```
  Host server
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 5m
  ```

  and then run your favorite command:

  ```
  scp me@server:/path/to/*_{Hello,World,SU}.txt
  ```
- Use `sftp` with batch file, which provides more flexibility in more complex cases:

  ```
  sftp -b <( echo get /path/to/*_{Hello,World,SU}.txt ) me@server
  ```